# About Dense layer learning same pattern in Deep Learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

When we pass the inputs to a Hidden Dense layer, Is It possible that most of neurons are learning same pattern while some are getting ignored or is there any mechanism that prevents neuron from having same weights ?  My question might be Vague, so correct me If I'm wrong or something i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *"most of neurons are learning same pattern,"* but there are several ways to prevent issues of the model being biased or not learning properly.

1. For *"some are getting ignored,"* there is **Dropout**.
2. There are a few methods to *"prevent neurons from having the same weights,"* including the aforementioned **Dropout**.
   For instance, proper **Weights Initialization** for the activation function (such as Xavier, He, etc), **L1 & L2 Regularization**, make model simpler, and use bigger dataset

Answer (score 0):

These are general approaches:

1. Use augmentation to have diverse inputs.
2. Increase your dataset size if possible
3. Use dropout
   https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html

Also random initialization helps in learning different patterns.